# neo4j aggregation on relations for a matched graph

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I've this cypher case where i need to get the strength of a relation to utilize a better recommendation, my case has an `A`, `B`, `C` nodes with relations `(A)-[:HAS {weight:n}]-(B)`, `(A)-[RESPONSIBLE {weight:n}]-(C)`, what i want to get is the relation between `(B)--(C)` and to calculate weight of each `C` with `A` as weight.

I tried this query which is obviously wrong but that what i could do so far

`MATCH (c:C {title:"some title"})
MATCH p=(c)<-[:RESPONSIBLE]-(A)-[:HAS]->(B)
RETURN DISTINCT(c.title) AS c, count(c.id) AS weight
ORDER BY weight DESC`

can you guys help ?

Comment: Can't tell what you're asking.  Do you mean there is a separate (not matched here) relationship between B and C?  If so, do a separate `OPTIONAL MATCH` for it.  What does "calculate weight of each C with A as weight" mean?  I don't see A.weight in your example here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, you want to sum up the weight of all `:HAS` relationships?

```
MATCH (c:C {title:"some title"})
MATCH p=(c)<-[:RESPONSIBLE]-(A)-[r:HAS]->(B)
RETURN DISTINCT(c.title) AS c, sum(r.weight) AS weight
ORDER BY weight DESC
```

Comment: Thank you @Brakebein thats exactly what i needed, i did it using multiple queries, but this way better :)